# Javascript anchor href change and form post

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom-events

I have a form coded like below. Basically the href value for the anchor tag is determined by the value selected in a dropdown.

```
<form name=xyz method=post>
  //random stuff

  <a href="#" onclick="setAnchor()">
    //some image
  </a>
</form>
```

I am setting the href property of the form  in javascript like this:

```
if(dropdown.option selected = "x")
    windows.location.href = some URL;
else
    windows.location.href = another URL;
```

The problem I am having is that using `windows.location` causes the form to use the GET method. The code expects a POST method to continue.

How can I fix this? I am not married to the above method. Any way I can set the form action URL, based on the option selected by the user, would work for me.

Answer (score 3):

If you have this form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="page.php" method="POST">
```

You can submit it (with a `POST` method) (that is, instead of `window.location...`) like so:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```

You can also set the URL to be submited like this

```
document.getElementById("myForm").action = "page.php";
```

Comment: The problem is that my form "action" changes depending on the option the user selected in another dropdown.So I use the windows.location.href to set the form action....which causes the for to use GET, instead of POST.

Comment: Use `document.getElementById("myForm").action = "page.php";` **instead** of `location.href` and **then** submit the form. This way the data will be sent by POST not GET.

Answer (score 0):

You should submit your form:

```
document.xyz.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.xyz.action=page1.php; (or page2.php based on dropdown selection)
document.xyz.submit();
```